# Search element in comma separated list based on substring match in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have list of data containing comma separated department wise orders in column-B, which is outlined in a format like:

> Order_Num-X1|Dept_Name-Y1,Order_Num-X2|Dept_Name-Y2

and so on...

See the below table: [image: Sample Data]

Is it possible to split and distribute the data in corresponding department column as outlined in Column-C, Column-D, Column-E?
I tried as suggested in this [post](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/comma-separated-values-as-criteria-in-filter-function-sheets/), But I stuck filtering a separated list stored in a single cell.

Comment: take a look at this custom "unpivot" function I wrote by making a copy of this sheet.  See the tab called "example with Split()"
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yJbz8QHFUVa19AzVmk9zL5wUI2h-cX7pgjYSiI7HwNA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(query(trim(split(flatten($A$2:$A&"|"&split($B$2:$B,",")),"|")),"select Col2 where Col3='"&C$1&"' and Col1='"&$A2&"' ",0)))
```

[image]

Comment: You might be interested in this...
https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/rrdpoy/a_journey_from_flatten_to_unpivot/

Comment: @MattKing thx, I have already seen your perfect script! What I way looking here is a formula to give an alternate!

Comment: it wasn't the script so much i was pointing out.  It was the story behind flatten if you didn't know :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm not as comfortable with the reduce() yet, but you've given me the opportunity to try a few things out once again. Your sheet is very clear and helpful. However, as far as I understand here, it is not an unpivot application but how to dispatch.